# Custom sublime build opens up a console

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using SublimeText 3 and I've followed [this](http://michaelcrump.net/getting-sublime-3-to-launch-your-html-page-in-a-browser-with-a-key-combo/) tutorial for opening files in browser. I have in my `Chrome.sublime-build` file

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\/Program Files (x86)\/Google\/Chrome\/Application\/chrome.exe", "$file"]
}
```

All of this works, and my files will be opened in Chrome, which is what I want, but at the same time the console pops up and says

```
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

which is super annoying.

Any way to stop console from opening?

I tried adding `false` as a third argument but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all build systems in Sublime tell you how long it took them to execute. If you don't want that, you need to add the following to your build system:

```
"quiet": true
```

Don't forget that all of the parts of the build system need to be separated with commas in order to be valid JSON.